# Calculation of area using definite integral

Tags: calculus

Find area bounded by function $\left\lfloor x \right \rfloor dx$ within limits $-3 $ to $4$, 
where $\left\lfloor x \right \rfloor $ is the floor function.
I have tried finding it but the answer is $0$.

Comment: The area of regions where the function is negative must be taken as negative.

Comment: Why do you believe your answer is false if you calculated it ?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Add up the areas of some rectangles....

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question? In other words, are you looking for the *area* or the *signed area* between $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and the $x$-axis and between $x=-3$ and $x=4$? The wording matters. The total *signed* area, where areas below the $x$-axis are considered to be negative, is actually zero, but the *unsigned area* is not. See which one you really need.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture:

The area on $[0,4] = 6$ units. The "signed" area on $[-3,0] = -6$ units, while "unsigned" area is just $6$ units.

The area on $[-3,4]$ is thus either $12$ or $0$, depending on if you mean unsigned area or signed area respectively.

[image]